# How to get parent element from database using Laravel relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship, laravel-8

I want to get all SubCourse parents. In example: I have HTML Course in database, and HTML has 1 subcourse, HTML flex, and I want to get HTML flex parent, the HTML Course.

I tried this but I get error:

```
$subCourses = SubCourse::with('courses')->get()
```

**Course.php**

```
class Course extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
    ];

    public function sub_courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCourse::class);
    }
}
```

**SubCourse.php**

```
class SubCourse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Course::class, 'course_id');
    }
}
```

**Course migration**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
        });
    }
```

**SubCourse migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('sub_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->foreignId('course_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

The solution is:

```
 return $this->belongsTo(Course::class, 'course_id');
```

Comment: change SubCourse model to `return $this->belongsTo(Course::class);`

Comment: I get return null.

Comment: `SubCourse::with('courses')->get()` does it return `course_id` as null on `dd`?

Comment: Yes, i tried it in tinker.

Comment: probably `course_id ` is null, check your table

Comment: course_id is good, but course is null.

Comment: Then your schema is wrong, cause you cant enter a foreign_key if the key id not exist on parent table, did you delete the parent?

Comment: No. Everything is fine with my schema. When I clicked the course_id in phpmyadmin it work well.

Comment: I solved it. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try This By Changing Relations ship into SubCourse Model

SubCourse.php

```
class SubCourse extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Course::class,'course_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: This return null.